# How to perform information extraction from news paper articles with a NLP library?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, opennlp

I am doing university final year project, My task is to extract causalities from news containing crime. I need to extract also location of crime. I used OPENNLP name entity recognizer to extract location. I trained a model for location names and its working fine for my scenario till now. Now I am searching some thing(a way OR a library) to extract causality. Here is a snap shot of a news which i am using and the Bold and Italic text is that which I want to extract. Need help for a library for this purpose same like OPENNLP, or any thing which can be useful or me in order to perform this task.

> News 1:
>
> KARACHI: At least ***12 people were gunned down*** in the city on Monday, two of them
>       apparently killed in sectarian attacks and one of the other victims a Muttahida Qaumi 
>       Movement activist.
>
> News 2:
>
> KARACHI: Police on Tuesday ***arrested three accused*** in different raids at Gulistan-e-Jauhar and Brigade areas, Geo News reported.
>
> News 3:
>
> KARACHI: ***Five members of a family were found dead*** inside their house in Baldia Town here on Monday, Geo News reported.
>
> News 4:
>
> KARACHI: Sindh Rangers in their continued targeted operation in the city last night ***rounded up eight professional criminals*** and recovered weapons from them, Geo News reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to pull out causality by using the parser, chunker, or part of speech tagger to identify verb phrases and noun phrases. This can be done by something like extracting consecutive verb and noun phrases.
this is how to use the parser, which will give you the entire sentence structure to play with, you will need to download the parser model

use this class (I put one of your sentences in)

```
public class ParseMap {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("c:\\temp\\opennlpmodels\\en-parser-chunking.bin");
    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
    is.close();
    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
    String sentence = "KARACHI: At least 12 people were gunned down in the city on Monday, two of them apparently killed in sectarian attacks and one of the other victims a Muttahida Qaumi Movement activist.";
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 1);
    Parse p = topParses[0];
    p.showCodeTree();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(sentence.length()*4);
    p.show(sb);
    System.out.println(sb);
  }
}
```

the output looks like this (held in the stringbuffer)

(TOP (S (`` KARACHI:) (S (NP (QP (IN At) (JJS least) **(CD 12)) (NNS people)) (VP (VBD were) (VP (VBN gunned) (ADVP (RB down))** (PP (IN in) (NP (NP (DT the) (NN city)) (PP (IN on) (NP (NP (NNP Monday,) (CD two)) (PP (IN of) (NP (PRP them))))))) (ADVP (RB apparently)) (VP (VBD killed) (PP (IN in) (NP (JJ sectarian) (NNS attacks))))))) (CC and) (S (NP (NP (CD one)) (PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (JJ other) (NNS victims)))) (NP (DT a) (NNP Muttahida) (NNP Qaumi) (NNP Movement))) (. activist.)))

notice how the causality you are looking for is a noun verb combo following one of your named entities (Karachi). With some tinkering you may be able to get some decent results.

EDIT: just to be clear, what I wrote was a suggestion to get something *quick*, you should be looking at some linguistic heuristics for this, and make sure what you want is actually causality, and not just event extraction, which you may be able to achieve training an NER model.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me check this over some of news then will get back to u.

Comment: I have trained a OPENNLP NER model with 40 news like that
<START:location> QUETTA <END> <START:killed> Two minors <END> were killed and <START:injured> three <END> others sustained injuries when the <START:crimeType> leaked Sui gas <END> in a house caused an <START:crimeType> explosion <END> at the  on <START:day> Tuesday <END> here Geo News reported.

Then i used this model for a unseen news it start giving my desired output...
What you say is this a good way ?i mean i train it over some more news i guess upto 300 its accuracy gots better..

Comment: Looks good (interesting taxonomy), as long as you train enough it will do its best to give you what you need.